# SQL Server View to get all childs and parents from parent child hierarchical structure table

Tags: sql-server, view, hierarchy

I have a table say **(cid, name, parent_cid)** named **categories** in Sql Server 2012.
Now, **when i search something in a specific category i need to search in all its child(including all grand childs) and all its parents(including grand parents) categories.**

Currently i am using a stored procedure to get all the childs and parents of the provided category and than filter on their basis and return results.

Of-course this is not a good solution and waste of resources.
It would be better **to have a View for this. Where i can get all the parents and childs of a category(including itself).**

i cans say view might look like something:
**cid (represents the cid i am interested to get all childs and parents of)

related_cids (has all the child and parents of this cid)**


than i can do 
**select related from my_view where cid=SOMEID;**
 and i will have all the parents and chidls of the provided SOMEID
This view i am looking for might also not be a good solution. So either this view or any other solution to this problem will be great.
Thankyou in advance.
**EDIT:**
Clarification-> I don't yet have the view, i am looking for how to create a view which will do the mentioned task. Hope its clearer now.

**EDIT2:** I have included the current stored procedure i am using to get all the parents and childs of a specific category. I tried converting it to the view as per i have explained before but was not successful. because i am looking for a view where i can have all the childs and parents of all the categories against them in the table.
 but current procedure returns all the parent and child categories with their respective immediate parent and their names.

```
create procedure mysp_getAllChildAndParentCategories @id INT as
WITH Parent AS (
    SELECT cid, name, parent_cid
    FROM category
    WHERE cid = @Id
UNION ALL
    SELECT a.cid, a.name, a.parent_cid
    FROM category a
    INNER JOIN Parent B ON B.cid = A.parent_cid
), 
    --Get Childs of @Id
Child AS (
        SELECT cid, name, parent_cid
        FROM category
        WHERE cid = @Id 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT a.cid, a.name, a.parent_cid
        FROM category A
        INNER JOIN Child B ON B.parent_cid = A.cid
        )

    SELECT * FROM Parent
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Child;
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here? What are you trying to do? Have you looked at a recursive cte?

Comment: Yes i have and thats what i am using in the stored procedure.
Can i ask what is the ambiguity in my question? so i may clarify

Comment: Well your question seems to be "is this a good approach?", which is off-topic because it's a matter of opinion, and also too broad to answer because it depends on too many factors that are not expressed in your question, like what the purpose of the view would be.   Why do you think your stored procedure is a bad approach?

Comment: ok let em edit to clerify.

Comment: Ok, now what isn't clear is why can't you just take the code from your stored procedure and turn it into a view?   What part of this do you not know how to do?   What code do you have now?   Please post the code of your stored procedure where you say you are currently using a recursive cte.

Comment: I tried actually, but failed to get desired results.
i am editing and including the code of the procedure here.

Comment: I hope its clear now, i have included the procedure now. Hope to get view i am looking for.<br>Besides i am curious, will there be any difference in performance if i use view against my current approach of calling this procedure each time for any cid i receive.